What is the Coulson-Fischer method of Quantum Chemistry
Recently, after understanding how the Valence Bond theory and Molecular Orbital Theory are similar through the "Modern Valence Bond Theory", I stumbled upon the Coulson-Fischer method. This method is considered a third way of Quantum chemistry and explains bonding with a mixture of Characteristics of Tradition Valence Bond Theory and Molecular Orbital Theory. In fact, it is an extension of the modern Valence Bond theory which are calculations of Valence Bond Theory which demonstrates how Wavefunction of VB theory is an average of ground, excited, ionic states. The Coulson Fischer method also talks about idea of relative delocalization in molecules. However I can't understand clearly about how Coulson-fischer method describes bonding intermediate between Valence Bond Theory and the Molecular Orbital Theory So What does the Coulson-Fischer method say about how atoms bond. I understand that it is a very new and although with its great potential doesn't have much research but I would be appreciative if anyone could answer.
It also links to the General Valence Bond theory which is similar to Modern Valence Bond Theory and is described as having remarkable accuracy

See the Wikipedia article and C.A. Coulson and I. Fischer, Notes on the Molecular Orbital Treatment of the Hydrogen Molecule, Phil. Mag. 40, 386 (1949)

More generally note the methods that include MOT and VBT are really a spectrum of related methods, and merge into one another; for instance MCSCF and GVB though coming from different "schools" are very closely related. The Coulson-Fischer method is "just" another method on this spectrum.

@Ian Bush I can't understand what the wikipedia says at all. I know modern VBT is use of multiple structures together to describe molecule but this method talks about starting with localized orbitals, using delocalization parameters and ending with delocalization. I can't even understand its wavefunction. So I was asking about if anyone could help me understand wavefunction and how coulson-fischer method describe bonding. (Sort of decode the wikipedia)

I'm afraid the whole of this are is inherently extremely mathematical, and you will struggle to follow in any sort of detail if you don't have the mathematical tools. For instance VBT doesn't use multiple structures. There is only one molecular structure. It (usually) uses multiple determinants to describe the wavefunction.  But so does Molecular Orbital theory, except at its very lowest level. The devil really is in the detail, and I honestly don't see how you can give it justice it without careful mathematical definition of the steps - handwaving is insufficient.

@Ian Bush Take Modern VBT which uses multiple structures to give multiple determinants to find wavefunction. When compared to Heitler and Londons Classical Localized VB method, the wavefunction was shown to be incomplete. Is there are difference in how they represent bonding then. Also Coulson Fischer is described as an add on of Modern VBT with charactersitics similar to VBT and MOT. I understand mathematics but wikipedia talks about how it describes bonding - delocalization, mixed properties so outlines bond dissociation energy. However It doesn't explain it clearly.

@Ian Bush It is even described as 3rd quantum chemical representation of bonding and shows bonding in intermediate between VBT and MOT.

@Ian Bush Also if multiple determinants are used to describe the wavefunction, shouldn't it relate to the image it gives about what happens when atoms bond
